# What's the difference between the following function arguments involving channels in Go?

Tags: function, go, arguments, channel

This code with the **channel operator** in the function argument:

```golang
func Worker(item <- chan string)
```

And this code **without** the channel operator in the function argument:

```golang
func Worker(item chan string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> func Worker(item <- chan string)

Here `item` is a send channel. You can only send value to it can't receive from it.

> func Worker(item chan string)

Here `item` is a bidirectional channel. Both send and receiving is possible.

Comment: Thanks. Someone gave an answer with the link to a specific Golang documentation. But I find this answer with a clear, brief explanation according to the developer's perspective.

Answer (score 5):

> The optional <- operator specifies the channel direction, send or
>   receive. If no direction is given, the channel is bidirectional. A
>   channel may be constrained only to send or only to receive by
>   conversion or assignment.

From golang spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code example to simulate channel direction.

```
// func Worker(item <- chan string) # Send or Receive
// func Worker(item chan string)    # Bidirectional

func sendOrRecvFunc(item <-chan string, msg *string) {
    *msg = <- item // send
}

func bidirectionalFunc(item chan string, msg string) {
    item <- msg // receive
}

func main() {

    // e.g Send or Receive
    var msg1 string

    item1 := make(chan string,1)

    item1 <- "message1" // receive

    sendOrRecvFunc(item1,&msg1)

    fmt.Println(msg1)

    //---------------------------------------------

    // e.g Bidirectional
    item2 := make(chan string,1)

    bidirectionalFunc(item2,"message2")

    msg2 := <- item2 // send

    fmt.Println(msg2)

}

// Output:
message1
message2
```